# Pegar valor das <td> com JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Olá, estou tentando desenvolver um mini jogo em JS, e preciso buscar os atributos dos personagens, dentro de tabelas, e usar para calcular as probabilidades, porém ja tentei de muitas maneiras e só consigo null, ou undefined.

Nesse  caso eu deveria pegar o valor da destreza e multiplicar pela agilidade, mas não estou conseguindo nem capturar os valores.

```js
function ataque() {
    var gp = document.getElementById('destre');
    var destreza = gp.value;    
    alert(destreza);
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="container-1">
            <div class="status-1">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Força</td>
                        <td>500</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Destreza</td>
                        <td id="destre">500</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Agilidade</td>
                        <td>500</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Constituição</td>
                        <td>500</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Carisma</td>
                        <td>500</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Inteligenca</td>
                        <td>500</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-2"></div>

        <div class="status-2">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Força</td>
                    <td>400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Destreza</td>
                    <td>400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Agilidade</td>
                    <td>400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Constituição</td>
                    <td>400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Carisma</td>
                    <td>400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Inteligenca</td>
                    <td>400</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

    </div>

    <button type="submit" onclick="ataque()"> atacar </button>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Você pode fazer assim. faz o teste:
Praticamente o querySelectorAll retorna uma *lista* de elementos presentes no documento a partir do seletor e você pode iterar sobre ele.

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.main tr td')[0].textContent)




// TESTA AI

    // Aqui eu pego todas as <TR> pais
    const tds = document.querySelectorAll('.main tr');

    for (td of tds) {
        // rodando o lopping com elas eu pego as td filhas onde 
        // [0] é o primeiro td e [1] é o segundo td
        let name = td.children[0];
        let value = td.children[1]; 
        console.log(name.innerHTML + ' : ' + value.innerHTML);
    }




  // Ou se quiser selecionar somente algum valor especifico, por_ 
  //  _classe ou por ID

  // Duas formas de pegar somente um elemento
  const destreza = document.querySelector('.main #destre');
  const destrez = document.getElementById('destre');

  console.log(destreza.textContent, destrez.textContent)
  alert('A destreza é: ' + destreza.textContent)
```

Comment: Não entendi os negativos sendo que funciona perfeitamente e supre a pergunta.?

Comment: Na pergunta ele não consegue pegar o atributos das tds e eu resolvi isso. Não está claro?